# How do I use multiple sources with the jQuery plugin fullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I've got a functional fullCalendar http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ working retrieving a single source from Google Calendar for the events like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

   events: $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed(
      "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/etc",   // feed URL
      { className: 'gcal-events' }                  // optional options
   )

     });
```

My challenge is however to have multiple feeds coming in. The fullCalendar documentation says:

eventSources: Array
    Similar to the 'events' options, except one may specify multiple sources. For example, one may specify an array of JSON URL’s, an array of custom functions, an array of hardcoded event arrays, or any combination.

But there is no example and so this JSON newbie here is a little bit stuck.

Any ideas on what it would need to use eventSources and an array of the feeds?

Comment: Looking to do this exact same thing. I'll keep poking at it and see how I go.

Comment: cosmicbdog (or a mod-powered fellow) can you please add the tag 'fullcalendar'. See the request in the comments to my answer.
Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found solution here;
http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=192&q=eventSources

```
eventSources:
[
    'msCal.txt', // location of Cal JSON script
    'msLogBook.txt', // location of LogBook JSON object
    'msEvents.txt' //location of the Events JSON object
]
```

Painfully simple in retrospect. The following is working on my test page;

```
eventSources:
[
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.australian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/usa__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic'),
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/en.indonesian%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/basic')
],
```

Comment: genius in its simplicity :) tx Tyronomo

Comment: Tyronomo, glad you got this to work. I am the creator of FullCalendar, and I want to begin keeping track of all FullCalendar-related questions on StackOverflow. Would you be so kinda as to edit this post, and add the tag "fullcalendar"? I'm gong to start monitoring this tag, it would be a great help. thanks!

Comment: arshaw, I will add is similar comment to the question asking cosmicbdog to update. There are no tags for answers. :(

Comment: But how do you add these sources, dynamically?

Comment: I have not used fullcalendar for a while, and no longer have my test page to check. But I would imagine you could edit/update/replace the eventSources array then redraw/refresh the calendar object. Sounds OK in my head, tho I have been using grids and datasourses for the last couple months, I could be completely wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and the idea above worked for me with a slight modification. I needed it to show 5 calendars on a page but only 1 calendar on a different page so I did this.

```
<?php if (is_page("calendar")):?>
 events:'...google calendar url #1...',
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (is_page("meeting-schedule")):?>
  eventSources: [
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('...google calendar url #1...'),
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('...google calendar url #2...'),
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('...google calendar url #3...'),
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('...google calendar url #4...'),
    $.fullCalendar.gcalFeed('...google calendar url #5...')
  ],
<?php endif; ?>
```

Works perfectly!!!