# FullCalendar: Using JSON feed containing a dynamic quantity of event sources

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I have a case where I need to display multiple eventSources on a calendar, but don't know the quantity of sources until runtime. I've created a javascript function with an AJAX call to a PHP script to create a valid JSON feed (verified with an online tool), and am trying to drop that JSON data into the initialization of the calendar. I've tried it with FullCalendar 1.6.4 and 2.0.0 and it doesn't display any events or throw any errors. The odd part is I can copy the stringified version of the JSON feed into the eventSources and it works. Any ideas?

Here's the stringified JSON data:

```
 [
  {
    "url": "/s/events.php?e=7",
    "type": "GET",
    "color": "#ffcc00",
    "textColor": "#000000"
  },
  {
    "url": "/s/events.php?e=59",
    "type": "GET",
    "color": "#ff6600",
    "textColor": "#ffffff"
  }
 ]
```

Heres the FullCalendar initialization code with the JSON data (dataSources not stringified):

```
 function loadCal(dataSources) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
            dataSources // Here's the JSON data
        ],
        editable: true,
        ...
 }
```

I've tried using the stringified version of dataSources and that results in an unusable URL (e.g., test.com/[%7B%22url%22:%20%22/s/events.php?e=7%22,%22type%22:%20%22GET%22,%22color%22:%20%22).

I'm open to suggestions of alternate approaches. Thanks.

Here's the code as I updated following the suggestion by Bhutto:

```
 function loadCal() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        eventSources: [
            function() {
                var userData = $.ajax( {
                    url: '/s/calendar_userdata.php',
                    method: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(userData) {
                        //console.log(userData);
                        var user_count = userData.length;
                        var source = [];
                        var jsonData = [];
                        // Create the sources
                        for (var i = 0; i < user_count; i++)
                        {
                            var uid = userData[i].uid;
                            if(!source[i]) source[i] = [];
                            source[i] = '/s/events.php?e=' + uid;

                            // Add each source to a JSON feed object
                            jsonData.push({
                                url: source[i],
                                type: 'GET',
                                color: userData[i].cal_color,
                                textColor: userData[i].txt_color,
                                error: function() { alert('There was an error loading calendar data.');}
                            });
                        }
console.log(jsonData); // In the console I can see well formed JSON data
                        return jsonData;
                    }
                }); 
            }
        ],
        editable: true,
```

Comment: dataSources contains json data???? Try like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778318/multiple-eventsources-with-jquery-fullcalendar

Comment: Thanks @bhutto. Yes, dataSources is the JSON data. The link you provide is a solution for providing FullCalendar with a feed of events. I was trying to provide FullCalendar a set of event sources, so that FullCalendar can get the event list. I'm trying to use as much of FullCalendar's code as possible. Inspired by your suggestion, I modified the code (see above) to generate the JSON data within the eventSource and still don't get any results in the calendar. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Did you use echo `json_encode($array);` in your calendar_userdata.php?

Comment: Yes, @KevinO'Brien. There are two queries in the code. One at URL and one (at least one) at source[i]. Both finish with "echo json_encode($results)" where $results is the result of the MySQL query.